# what is this で in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-で

In the examplatory phrases of my grammar, there is this sentence.
本当の研究発表のつもり**で**、みんなの前ではなしてください。

"Please talk in front of everybody as if it was a real presentation of your new research."

I'd just like to know how this で in bold has to be classified. I'd say it is a connector like in な adjectives, but since I don't know how to classify つもり, I wanted to ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The で you've marked is the case-marking particle (格助詞) で. As for つもり, it is a noun.

> つもり**で** = **with** the "intention"
>
> 本当の研究発表のつもりで、みんなの前ではなしてください。= Please talk in front of everybody with the intention of the real research presentation.